# Security in Windows Update Procedure?

Tags: certificates, hash, windows

Assuming I have Windows 10 and updating Windows, how does Windows verify the integrity of the downloaded packages and how does the the download procedure work? I know that in Linux the packages are checked with checksums. But from where it will be checked? From the official download website or does the paketmanager do it by her own? And where can I find the downloaded packages and take a look at the hashes? Can someone explain me the Windows Update Procedure please?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know:

Windows 10 is using a technology called Unified Update Platform (UUP).
This Service works with differential download packages.
A differential download package contains only the changes that have been made since the last time you updated your device, rather than a full build.

**How does it work:**

The UUP Service sends a list with all installed Updates to UUP Cloud Service (the Azure Cloud),
the Cloud Service merges the list with the latest update list and tells the UUP Service if there are any new differential packages.
The UUP Service starts Downloading these differential packages.

You can find the downloaded differential packages in the *C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\Download* folder.

Source: https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2016/11/03/introducing-unified-update-platform-uup/#cD5BkKJkUTT2vory.97